# Find all the infinite cardinals $a$ such that $a^4 + 16^a = 16^a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Find all the infinite cardinals $a$ such that  $a^4 + 16^a = 16^a$.

I think this is equivalent to $a^4 + (2^a)^4 = (2^a)^4$, but I don't know how to prove the latter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Noah Schweber. Yes

Comment: When you write $2^{a^4}$ the default is to read it as $2^{(a^4)},$ not $(2^a)^4$.  For finite $a, 16^a \neq 2^{(a^4)}$ but for infinite $a$ it is true because $a^4=a$ and $16^a \ge 2^a=2^{4a}=(2^4)^a=16^a$

Comment: Why the `discrete-mathematics` tag?

Answer (score 1):

For all infinite cardinals under AC, $a^4=a, 16^a=2^a \gt a, a+b=\max(a,b)$

Comment: This is what I'm trying to prove

Comment: Usually these are proven in general and the exercise you have is intended to see if you recognize them.  Do you have $a^2=a$ and $a+a=a$?

Comment: No. How can it be proven? @Ross Millikan